# Python Bokeh - conditional table formatting + filter boxes

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

**Hello friends,**

**See code, current output and desired output below. What should be added to the code?**

---

- I would like to use bokeh in order to color cell values < 2 in green and cells between 2 and 9 in red.
- I would like to add filters to each table column.

**Sample output:**

---

[image]

**Desired output:**

---

[image]

---

```
    import pandas as pd
    d = {'A': ['A','B','C']}
    data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    data['B']=[7,8,9]
    data['C']=[1,2,3]

    from bokeh.io import output_file, show
    from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
    from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn, HTMLTemplateFormatter


    output_file(r'C:\Users\rbiberma\Desktop\TEMP\data_table.html')
    source = ColumnDataSource(data)
    column_list = data.columns
    columns = [TableColumn(field=col, title=col) for col in column_list]
    data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=200, height=100)
    show(data_table)
```

Comment: If you use Bokeh only to generate a DataTable then I would rather go for [SlickGrid](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html) instead. The previous link shows how to filter columns and [this example](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example14-highlighting.html) shows how to use formatter to change the cell background.

Comment: Not sure if it still works (have not tested with newer bokeh versions) but there are some possible workarounds - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740477/bokeh-datatable-with-conditionally-coloured-cells/42742954#42742954 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731757/how-do-i-adjust-number-format-in-bokeh-data-table-using-htmltemplateformatter/44734269#44734269